# How to hack a Kubernetes container with a Spring Boot application and running as a root user?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I run my Spring Boot application in the Kubernetes environment as a root user and with JMX authentication turned on.

My k8s containers are being flagged as a security risk by the security professionals in my company. Is it really a security risk or just plain old housekeeping?

Comment: The fact that your cluster allows running any container as root (or an elevated user) is a problem... Openshift for example wouldn't allow that. Your question is not specific to Spring Boot, but any attack vector into a Java app would apply

Comment: Perhaps, it might get more attention on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SlavaSemushin You're probably right!